# Display image slideshow by using php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have a database named hotel_booking,it contains field named imglinks which stores the link of the images and i am only able to display single image in the site. i want to display a slide show of the images of the respective hotels.

```
 <tr>
    <th>NAME OF HOTELS</th>
    <th>CATEGORY</th>
     <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    <th>ADDRESS</th>
    <th>GALLERY</th>
</tr>
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $f1=$row['name'];
        $f2=$row['category'];
        $f3=$row['description'];
        $f4=$row['address'];

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $f1 ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f2 ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f3 ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f4 ?></td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $row['imglinks'];?>" height="200" width="55"></td>
```

[link to image of what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV60U.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried jquery or bootstarp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap to achieve this easily with a few lines of code.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Go through this link and if there is any problem let me know :)

Comment: yeah i have done what you've said but the links need to be dynamic in my case as different hotels need to have different sets to images and i have only one link which is $imglinks.